# create container with the help of input fields and python

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to create a container with python.
The problem I'm facing is that my code doesn't create the container.

The input for the command is defined into input fields named:
inm, sc, hv, cv, hp, cp and cn

The code I made so far is:

```
 bestaande_containers = client.containers.list(all=True)
  for container in bestaande_containers:
      if container.name == cn:
         error = "<h2> de container met de naam "+ cn  +" bestaat al"
  return error
# strippen van het ! en de *
  inm = inm.replace("!","").replace("*"," ")
  sc = sc.replace("!"," ").replace("*"," ")
  hv = hv.replace("!","/").replace("*"," ")
  cv = cv.replace("!","/").replace("*"," ")
  hp = hp.replace("!","/").replace("*"," ")
  cp = cp.replace("!","/").replace("*"," ")
  cn = cn.replace("!","/").replace("*"," ")
#container maken aan de hand van de input
  client.containers.run(
  image = inm,
  command = sc,
  ports = {cp:hp},
  volumes = {hv:{"bind": cv, "mode": "rw"}},
  detach = True,
  name = cn,
  )

  print()

  OUTPUTHTML7="<h1>de Container: "+ cn +"is gemaakt</h1>"
  return OUTPUTHTML7
```

This code gives me the following errors:

```
172.17.0.7 - - [20/Feb/2023 22:35:45] "GET /opdracht7/jnapaserv-dev23-test//usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND//home/adios/Apafiles///var/www/html/8080/80/Testcontainer HTTP/1.1" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -

172.17.0.7 - - [20/Feb/2023 22:35:45] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('GET /opdracht7/jnapaserv-dev23-test//usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND//home/adios/Apafiles///var/www/html/8080/80/Testcontainer HTTP/1.1')
```

I have tried a couple of things, but cant seem to get it working.

Comment: *i have tried a couple*, so what have you tried? Can you summarize that briefly? Otherwise people will suggest things which you've tried already and didn't work for some reason. Perhaps also elaborate on what you're trying to do in the end, other people don't know what you're working on.

Comment: Remember that a bind-mounted host volume directory can be _any_ directory, even the host's `/etc` or your application's SSL key directory; you probably want to validate the `hv` parameter before launching the container.  If you do need to republish the Docker API this way, I might use HTTP query parameters or a JSON-format POST body rather than trying to split up the request path as you show.